# Disable read as well as write in an existing table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We have a table already existing in oracle 11g database which allows read as well as write operations. I want to block both read as well as write operations to the table. Can you please help?

Comment: _read_ and write? If it's in the same schema move schema otherwise just revoke the privileges. Is your table in the same schema as you're reading or writing from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [REVOKE command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/statements_9020.htm) to take permissions away from other users. You cannot revoke privileges from the table owner, however.

You could also export the table and then drop it. Nobody can read it then :-)